# Exact solution of Second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

We have the second order differential equation

$\epsilon \dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} + \dfrac{dy}{dx} +y = 0$

with boundary values $y(0)=0,\, \, \,  y(1)=1$.

I would like to get the exact solution in the form $$y(x) = C \exp(\alpha x)\sinh(\beta x)$$
with $\alpha, \beta$ and $C$ as constants.

I'm too sure how to go about this, I have tried to substitute the solution form into the differential equation but I don't think I am going in the right direction.

Comment: You may have tagged this [tag:asymptotics] and [tag:perturbation-theory].by mistake, since you seem to only be interested in an exact solution to the equation.

Comment: @AntonioVargas That might actually be an interesting meta question. Suppose the underlying topic behind the question is asymptotic solutions, but you are currently asking about a "toy problem" for which an exact solution can be determined. The interest is not really in the toy problem itself, but rather in using the toy problem to get a feel for the accuracy of the asymptotic solutions. Should the question be tagged asymptotics etc.? In my opinion it should, but the user should say a little bit about the context.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\epsilon \in (0,1/4)$. The general solution to your equation is linear combinations of $e^{r_1 x}$ and $e^{r_2 x}$ where $r_1,r_2$ solve $\epsilon r^2+r+1=0$. So your solution will be

$$c_1 e^{r_1 x} + c_2 e^{r_2 x}$$

where

$$c_1+c_2=0 \\
c_1 e^{r_1} + c_2 e^{r_2} = 1.$$

It is probably best to solve this system directly, rather than in the simplified form that you want. To actually get to your simplified form, first notice that the first equation tells you $c_1=-c_2$. Second, solve $r_1=\alpha-\beta,r_2=\alpha+\beta$. Then

$$c_1 e^{r_1 x} + c_2 e^{r_2 x} = c_1 e^{\alpha x} \left ( e^{-\beta x} - e^{\beta x} \right ) = -2 c_1 e^{\alpha x} \sinh(\beta x).$$